# How to connect an external display to a MacBook Pro Late 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I would like to connect an display (Dell LCD monitor P2715Q) to a MacBook Pro Late 2016.

When connecting via USB and Mini DisplayPort, the display still says that there is no signal from the computer. I can't insert the CD that came with monitor since this model of MacBook doesn't have an optical drive.

Is it driver issue (and where could I download them) or is it compatability issue?

Comment: What is the cable or adapter you are using to connect to the display?

Comment: Converter is original from apple

Comment: That one is for mDP. The second one is for USB - Satechi.

Comment: You still need to give more details. Give the exact name and model number of the converters. Try this format: "My xx inch touchbar/no Touch Bar late 2016 MBP is plugged into an Apple X to Y adapter..."

Comment: My 15" touch bar late 2016 MBP is plugged into two adapters: 1. mDP to usb C from Apple, 2. USB type A to usb C Satechi (multi-converter). I am trying to connect with display Dell P2715Q.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, there is no such thing as a mDP to USB-C converter from Apple. You are using the Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter. It does not convert DisplayPort signals, only Thunderbolt.

Comment: Oh, I asked them to double check that this is the adapter I need. I am no expert so I believed them.. I should probably get different adapter? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: I've only used HDMI, but buy a USB-C to DisplayPort adapter that has been reported by others to have worked on your model of computer.

Answer (score 0):

I helped a user with the exact same monitor last week. Assuming you have the correct cable/adapter, you need to press the MDP button on the side of the display, not the DP button. Once that was done, all started working properly.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. The display still claims there is no mDP cable/signal. Do you think cable or converter is bad?

Comment: Well, it is possible you could have a faulty adapter/cable. It's also possible you're not using the right one. Can you clarify exactly what you're using? In the case of the user I helped, they've used their display for a number of Macs over the past couple of years and it was only the 2017 MBP that had an issue. The adapter from Apple didn't work, so they bought one from Amazon. It wasn't until that didn't work that they came to me and we discovered the MDP and DP button. Does yours have this button? Have you also set your input source correctly, via the display's menu?

Comment: I connected the display via 2 cables which are the ones that came with display. For USB input I have multiconverter from Satechi and for the other original Apple converter for mDP. I tried with input menu and the answer is still the same "no mDP cable".